# reified and half-reified predicates

Tags: minizinc, flatzinc

It has been recently brought to my attention that some recent version of `FlatZinc` supports *half-reified predicates*:

> **Half-reified** predicates essentially represent constraints that are implied by a Boolean variable rather than being equivalent to one.
>
> source: [docs](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/fzn-spec.html?highlight=half%20reified#reified-and-half-reified-predicates)

**Q:**

- do all *global predicates* have a `_reif` version now?
- do all *global predicates* have a `_imp` version too?

Looking at the content of `share/minizinc/` I can see that inside `std` only `nosets.mzn` uses `_imp` predicates, so my impression is that it is not yet mandatory to support `_imp` predicates. **Q:** Is this correct?

Looking at the docs, I found this:

> Solver libraries should therefore provide reified versions of constraints whenever possible. The library contains files `fzn__reif.mzn` for this purpose.
>
> source: [docs](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/fzn-spec.html?highlight=half%20reified#reified-and-half-reified-predicates)

If I interpret it correctly, it is not necessary to support `_reif` predicates because they are already redefined in `share/minizinc` (although it can be beneficial for performance). **Q:** Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most often predicates (calls), `R(...)`, are used as an actual constraint: `constraint R(...)`. The question when processing the expression `R(...)` is now if it can be given directly to the solver or if it has a redefinition that needs to be evaluated.

If the predicate is used in a more complex expression `B \/ R(...)`, then we cannot just give the solver the call `R(...)` because we don't want to enforce `R(...)`. Instead we want to know if the relationship described by `R(...)` holds. This is what we call a reification.

For this reason, there must be a `R_reif(..., r)` predicate that forces `r <-> R(...)`. Essentially this give the truth value of `R(...)`. Again, when the compiler is given the expression `R_reif(...,r)`, then it will see if it can be given directly to the solver or if there is a redefinition available. If both of these are unavailable, then the compiler will try to generate a redefinition from the redefinition of `R(...)`. If this also fails, then the compiler will stop the compilation.

If we look back at our example, `B \/ R(...)`, then one might note that using `r <-> R(...)` is more than what is necessary. If `R(...)` is false, then we still need `B` to be `true` and if `B` is `false` we still want to force `R(...)`; however, we know that nothing will force `R(...)` to become `false`. We say `R(...)` is in a positive context. In this case that means that having `r -> R(...)` is enough. This is referred to as a [half-reification](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-23786-7_23).

In MiniZinc it is possible to introduce a `R_imp(..., r)` predicate to provide a separate half-reified predicate. This can again be something that is directly passed into the solver or a redefinition. If the compiler has to reify a expression `R(...)` and sees that it is in a positive context, then it will try first to see if it can find `R_imp(..., r)` and otherwise fall-back to `R_reif(..., r)`. Note that if a redefinition is generated, then the context of the call propagates inward and half reifications can still occur in the redefinition.

To summarise and answer your questions directly:

- All global predicates can be reified. A redefinition of the `_reif` can be defined explicitly or can be generated through the generation from their redefinition.
- None of the globals are half-reified. This is not necessary since half-reifications can still be triggered when generating redefinitions of reifications and there are currently no known cases where an explicit half-reified definition performs better.
- There are no currently half-reified predicates that have required solver support. Note however that any `_reif` predicate that can be implemented as `_imp` by the solver (including FlatZinc builtins).
- It is not required to support any global `_reif` predicates; however, there are several required `_reif` predicates in the FlatZinc builtins that *do* need support. If these predicates are not redefined or implemented by the solver, then the solver cannot support the generated FlatZinc.